# Closure of sets A and B

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f: (a,b) \to R$ be a differentiable map, $A = \left\{f'(x) : x \in (a,b) \right\}$ and $B = \left\{\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} : x  \neq y \in (a,b) \right\}$.

I need to prove that $\overline{B} = \overline{A}$;

It is easy to notice that $\overline{B} \subseteq \overline{A}$. The problem is, I need to show that $\overline{B} \supseteq \overline{A}$ to complete the proof.

Any ideas?

If this way is too difficult, I can maybe try to find the closure of A and B and show they're the same set.

Comment: This was asked just one or two days ago.

Comment: You may check my comment in your now-deleted post. The idea is that differential quotients are limits of difference quotients, hence the elements of $A$ are limit points of of $B$.

Comment: @SangchulLee I have no idea how can I start from differential quotients. I'll search about it

Comment: You posted this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4327628/), then deleted it and reasked it here.  Why?

Comment: Additional to it, any hints about how can we find $\sup B$ and $\inf A$ using the MTV?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know that $\overline{A}$ is the smallest (regarding set inclusion) closed set containing $A$.

Fix $x\in(a,b)$. For every $\epsilon>0$,
$$\lvert f'(x)-\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\rvert<\epsilon$$
provided only that $y\not=x$ is sufficiently close to $x$, so that $f'(x)\in\overline{B}$. This means that $A\subset\overline{B}$ and hence $\overline{A}\subset\overline{B}$.

Conversely, let $x,y\in(a,b)$, $x\not=y$. By the mean value theorem, there exists $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$ such that
$$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=f'(\xi)\in A\mbox{.}$$
Thus $B\subset A$ and hence $\overline{B}\subset\overline{A}$.